# CollapsedToolbar doesnt get open with fling

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library

[image: CollapsedToolbar doesnt get open with fling]

Its a self-explanatory question. I can't get collapsed toolbar to expand with fling gesture in nestedScrollView. After fling gesture(notice the overglow) i have scroll to top manually to get the toolbar to expand. I tried the some variations of scroll flags such as scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed etc. 
Is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: If anyone wonders i fixed it with extending the scrollView

Comment: Would you mind elaborate on the solution?

Comment: Why don't you post an answer? And, please, show code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im answering my own question if anyone would like to learn how i solved it:
Its pretty simple actually, I just listen if scrollview overscrolled (check the glow on the gif) and throw an event. Im also checking if user still touching so it doesn't get expanded suddenly

```
public class NestedScrollViewFling extends NestedScrollView
{
    private OnFlingEndReachedTopListener mListener;
    private Boolean isBeingTouched = false;

    public NestedScrollViewFling(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public NestedScrollViewFling(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                 int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public NestedScrollViewFling(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        int action = ev.getAction();

        if ((action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) || (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE))
            isBeingTouched = true;
        else
            isBeingTouched = false;

        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY)
    {
        if (clampedY && scrollY == 0)
        {
            if (mListener != null)
                mListener.onTopReached(isBeingTouched);
        }

        super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);
    }

    public OnFlingEndReachedTopListener getOnTopReachedListener()
    {
        return mListener;
    }

    public void setOnTopReachedListener(
            OnFlingEndReachedTopListener onTopReachedListener)
    {
        mListener = onTopReachedListener;
    }

    /**
     * Event listener.
     */
    public interface OnFlingEndReachedTopListener
    {
        public void onTopReached(Boolean isBeingTouch);
    }
}
```

And on the activity set the listener

```
scrollView.setOnTopReachedListener(new NestedScrollViewFling.OnFlingEndReachedTopListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onTopReached(Boolean isBeingTouched)
    {
        if (!isBeingTouched)
            expandToolbar();
    }
});
```

Lastly the expandToolbar method and handler

```
public void expandToolbar()
{
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appbarLayout.getLayoutParams();
    AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
    if (behavior != null && !stop)
    {
        behavior.onNestedFling(coordinatorLayout, appbarLayout, null, 0, -10000, false);
        stop = true;
        useHandler();
    }
}

Handler mHandler;
Boolean stop = false;

public void useHandler()
{
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 200);
}

private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        stop = false;
    }
};
```

While experimenting on my code, i found out that changing -10000 value in expandToolbar method to "-appbarLayout.getHeight() * 5 makes the animation smoother.

Cheers.